# Nutrition history data returns always 1st item from Google Fit on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

I am trying to query nutrition history data from Google Fit on Android.

The data is inserted via the food-logging app ([Lose It](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fitnow.loseit)).

But when I query the data from the Google Fit History client it retrieves the data only for the first item I inserted in the app.
i.e. If I log breakfast with juice and bagel, the macros that will be retrieved from the client are only for the bagel.

My code:

```
val nowInMillis = 1625656053000;
val weekAgoInMillis = 1625137653000;

val fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION)
    .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_NUTRITION_SUMMARY)
    .build()

val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(activity, fitnessOptions)

coroutineScope.launch {

    Fitness.getHistoryClient(activity, account)
        .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_NUTRITION)
        .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
            for (dp in response.dataPoints) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Data point:")
                Log.i(TAG, "\tType: ${dp.dataType.name}")
                Log.i(
                    TAG, "\tStart: ${
                        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                            timeInMillis = dp.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        }.time
                    }")
                Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "\tEnd: ${
                        Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                            timeInMillis = dp.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        }.time
                    }")
                for (field in dp.dataType.fields) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "\tField: ${field.name.toString()} Value: ${dp.getValue(field)}")
                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.d(TAG, "OnFailure()", e) }
}
```

The printed result:

```
2021-07-06 22:55:17.988 30237-30237/com.metaflow.flutterhealthfitexample I/FlutterHealthFitPlugin:  Type: com.google.nutrition.summary
2021-07-06 22:55:17.992 30237-30237/com.metaflow.flutterhealthfitexample I/FlutterHealthFitPlugin:  Start: Tue Jul 06 01:00:01 GMT+03:00 2021
2021-07-06 22:55:17.996 30237-30237/com.metaflow.flutterhealthfitexample I/FlutterHealthFitPlugin:  End: Tue Jul 06 01:00:01 GMT+03:00 2021
2021-07-06 22:55:18.002 30237-30237/com.metaflow.flutterhealthfitexample I/FlutterHealthFitPlugin:  Field: nutrients Value: {calories=111.6, carbs.total=25.792, cholesterol=0.0, dietary_fiber=0.496, fat.saturated=0.0496, fat.total=0.496, protein=1.736, sodium=2.48, sugar=20.832}
2021-07-06 22:55:18.002 30237-30237/com.metaflow.flutterhealthfitexample I/FlutterHealthFitPlugin:  Field: meal_type Value: 1
```

And if I look into the food logging app, I can see the next result, which clearly shows that nutrition info retrieved matches only juice:

[image: food logger screenshot]

I thought that maybe there is an issue with my code, so I downloaded a FitBit app, that able to show nutrition info from Google Fit as well, and it shows the same result:

[image: FitBit app result]

Any option to get nutrition info for a complete day?

Comment: Have you established that LoseIt is inserting data correctly? What do you see if you query for the day without aggregation (using `readData`)?